# C++ Partial Template Specialization and Natvis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, template-specialization, natvis

I'm trying to create Visual Studio debug visualizers for a partially specialized type. For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T*>
{
    T baz;
};
```

Without the partial specialization, this would be easy:

```
<Type Name="Foo&lt;*&gt;"> ... </Type>
```

With full specialization, it'd also be easy:

```
<Type Name="Foo&lt;int&gt;"> ... </Type>
```

But how do I cover the partial specialization? Is this even supported? If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - No. You can't specify type qualifiers, references, and so on in natvis type name `<Type Name="Foo&lt;*&gt;">`.

But:

You can use the template's typename parameter as a string and compare with a type. For example, in the node's `Condition` attribute:

```xml
<Type Name="Foo&lt;*&gt;">
  <DisplayString Condition="strcmp(&quot;$T1&quot;,&quot;short&quot;)==0">specialization short</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="strcmp(&quot;$T1&quot;,&quot;int &amp;&quot;)==0">specialization int &amp;</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString>unspecified specialization</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

For `Foo<short>` you will see `specialization short` and `unspecified specialization` for other.

Example:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;
};

template <typename U>
struct Foo<int &, U>
{
    U baz;
};
int main()
{
    int gg = 0;
    Foo<short, int> a;
    Foo<int, int> b;
    Foo<int &, int> c;
```

Natvis:

```xml
<Type Name="Foo&lt;*,*&gt;" >
  <DisplayString Condition="strcmp(&quot;$T1&quot;,&quot;short&quot;)==0">specialization short</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString>unspecified specialization</DisplayString>
</Type>

<Type Name="Foo&lt;int&amp;,*&gt;">
  <DisplayString>partial specialization int&amp;</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Result:

[image: strcmp]

Or you, if you have some unique member in your partially specialized type, can use `Priority` option.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;
};

template <typename U>
struct Foo<U &>
{
    U baz;
};
int main()
{
    int g = 0;
    Foo<short> a;
    Foo<int> b;
    Foo<int &> c{g};
```

Natvis:

```
<Type Name="Foo&lt;*&gt;">
  <DisplayString>partial specialization {baz}</DisplayString>
</Type>

<Type Name="Foo&lt;*&gt;" Priority="Low">
  <DisplayString>other specialization</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Result:

[image: Priority]

Comment: `Foo<short>` is a full specialization though. How would this syntax work for `template <typename T> Foo<T&>`?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful clarification! :)